# eduroam (WPA enterprise) no wifi when using wpa_supplicant.conf

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, wifi

I am trying to use my raspberry pi 3 on the eduroam network. I found quite a few post on how to do this. 
The first step mentions editing /etc/network/interfaces
Mine originally looked like:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
```

and I have added the following lines:

```
auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
 pre-up wpa_supplicant -B -Dwext -i wlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
 post-down killall -q wpa_supplicant
```

Then I added my new network to /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

```
network={
  ssid="eduroam"
  priority=1
  proto=RSN
  key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
  pairwise=CCMP
  auth_alg=OPEN
  eap=PEAP
  identity=""
  password=""
  phase1="peaplabel=0"
  phase2="auth=MSCHAPV2"
  }
```

## However I am unable to connect or restart wifi after this modification.

If I run

```
sudo wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

I get the following error:

```
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
ctrl_iface exists and seems to be in use - cannot override it
Delete '/var/run/wpa_supplicant/wlan0' manually if it is not used anymore
Failed to initialize control interface 'DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev'.
You may have another wpa_supplicant process already running or the file was
left by an unclean termination of wpa_supplicant in which case you will need
to manually remove this file before starting wpa_supplicant again.

nl80211: deinit ifname=wlan0 disabled_11b_rates=0
```

Is wpa_supplicants not used anymore? What cleanup is required? Is there an easier way to connect to eduroam?

many thanks

Jesse

**EDIT:**

reading through the link on setting up [WIFI](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37920/how-do-i-set-up-networking-wifi-static-ip-address/37921#37921) it is mentioned:

> wpa_supplicant-"$interface".conf in /etc/wpa_supplicant/ e.g. wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf will only be used by wlan0

so I copied my wpa_supplicant.conf to wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf and removed my modifications to `/etc/network/interfaces` and after rebooting am able to automatically connect. This is a much simpler solution.

Comment: In my answer I had suggested to `sudo systemctl disable wpa_supplicant.service`. You asked me: _Does this disable wpa_supplicants completely? or will it still start the service once booting gets to /etc/network/interfaces?_ I have checked that `wpa_supplicant.service` is disabled by default so my answer was wrong in this context. I have deleted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is wpa_supplicants not used anymore?

It is still used.

> What cleanup is required?

There can only be one instance of `wpa_supplicant` running per wifi interface.  First check if there is one:

```
ps -C wpa_supplicant
```

If there is anything other than the column headings (`PID TTY TIME CMD`), take the number from the PID column and:

```
sudo kill nnnn
```

Where "nnnn" is the PID number.  Then check to see it is gone.  If not, try `sudo kill -15 nnnn`.  If it is still running after that, reboot.

However, I do not think there will be much trouble that way; hopefully it isn't running at all. *If it is, this is probably because it is being run automatically by the networking service you configured,* in which case you will have to disable that.

Once you sort that out:

```
sudo file /var/run/wpa_supplicant/wlan0
```

If this says "socket":

```
sudo rm /var/run/wpa_supplicant/wlan0
```

That should remove the file.

Comment: thank you, killing the wpa_supplicant process, then removing  `/var/run/wpa_supplicant/wlan0` does the trick. How do i make this permanent? As in, when I restart I am unable to connect and have to repeat killing the process. I guess there is a startup file somewhere configuring wpa_supplicant before mine

Comment: That would be my guess.  I don't use the normal networking configuration system so I can't say much about it.