# How can I connect my Raspberry Pi Pico W to an Eduroam WiFi access point (WPA authentication)?

Tags: wifi, wireless, pi-pico, wpa, micropython

For [a teaching demo about autonomy in scientific research](https://hackaday.io/project/186289-autonomous-research-laboratories), it will likely be a major blocker if students cannot connect the Pico W to their school's WiFi.

Someone [suggested](https://github.com/orgs/micropython/discussions/9264) MAC spoofing, and I agree that this seems the easiest way to go; however, I also wonder if there's a way to connect a Pico W via WPA authentication to a network more directly.

Any additional thoughts or suggestions here? Any example code? I'd like to minimize the number of additional steps that a user needs to take to set up a network connection.

Related:

- https://github.com/orgs/micropython/discussions/9264
- https://forum.micropython.org/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=10405
- [eduroam (WPA enterprise) no wifi when using wpa_supplicant.conf](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/82758/eduroam-wpa-enterprise-no-wifi-when-using-wpa-supplicant-conf)

Comment: @jsotola, thanks for your suggestion. I condensed it.

Answer (score 1):

I found something that could be of help

https://docs.pycom.io/tutorials/networks/wlan/#connecting-to-a-wpa2-enterprise-network

**Connecting with EAP-TLS:**

Before connecting, obtain and copy the public and private keys to the device, e.g. under location /flash/cert. If it is required to validate the server’s public key, an appropriate CA certificate (chain) must also be provided.

```
from network import WLAN

wlan = WLAN(mode=WLAN.STA)
wlan.connect(ssid='mywifi', auth=(WLAN.WPA2_ENT,), identity='myidentity', ca_certs='/flash/cert/ca.pem', keyfile='/flash/cert/client.key', certfile='/flash/cert/client.crt')
```

**Connecting with EAP-PEAP or EAP-TTLS:**

In case of EAP-PEAP (or EAP-TTLS), the client key and certificate are not necessary, only a username and password pair. If it is required to validate the server’s public key, an appropriate CA certificate (chain) must also be provided.

```
from network import WLAN
wlan = WLAN(mode=WLAN.STA)
wlan.connect(ssid='mywifi', auth=(WLAN.WPA2_ENT, 'username', 'password'), [identity='myidentity', ca_certs='/flash/cert/ca.pem'])
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/125423)

Comment: This looks very promising! I'll plan on giving it a try with Eduroam

Comment: Still planning to try, but I'm not seeing some of the WLAN class properties that were listed above https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/network.WLAN.html

Comment: From what I understand and I am a noob at this. It's not possible to have eduroam on Pi Pico because the Micropython SDK for Pi Pico has not made that class and the C/C++ SDK has not either. Whereas the MicroPython SDK developed by Expressif who makes ESP32 has, so it's just not possible on a Pico. It has been demanded since 2019 I believe. Sad but true.